# How to map Ctrl-c to normal mode in zle?

Tags: zsh

In zsh with vi bindings, I want to leave insert mode not only using `Esc` but also using `Ctrl-c`. I tried this as suggested [in another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/253402/ctrl-c-not-working-in-zsh).

```
bindkey -M viins '^C' vi-cmd-mode
```

Pressing `Ctrl-c` still just creates a new prompt below the last one. How can I bind to `Ctrl-c` in insert mode in zle?

Comment: nitpick: `Zsh has no `vim` bindings, it has `vi` bindings. There is nothing `vim`-specific (as far as I know) about them.

Comment: @Celada Thanks for the correction. Would be cool to have vim functionality though.

Comment: If you like. Personally I learned on some sort of SysV version of `vi` and only know standard `vi`. The only reason I use `vim` today is because it's the most conveniently available `vi` variant that isn't totally broken by Unicode and such; but I have to use `vim`'s compatible mode because otherwise it greatly breaks my expectations.

Comment: I'd advise against this; `C-c` handling is already hilariously complicated, as the shell process is actually reacting to an `INT` signal that may or may not be blocked depending on what the shell is doing at that moment.

Comment: @Celada since version 5.0.8 `zsh` actually does [support some vim(-like) features](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/News/), such as text objects and visual mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to just remap interrupting to any other key ([1](http://www.unix.com/302095273-post2.html?s=bbf1b38a6e0cef77bd54477eca97d178)):

```
stty intr \^E
```

Comment: Works for me. You can do this with a precmd_function() and then undo it with a preexec_function() so that it only effects when you are typing at the prompt.